# Retrieve multiple columns from last Row in Table using Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am new to `C# LINQ` Queries.

I wish to access the last record in a table and retrieve the values of 2 columns from it.

Accessing the last row is not proving difficult as I can sort with descending order on a unique integer key where the greater value represents a later addition, but I am not sure how I can return 2 different values(integer and string) using a single query.

Would I have to perform 2 different queries, each querying for one item and return that, or would it be more efficient to have the whole lot in a string, and parse the string elsewhere?

This is what I have so far. I am not certain which way would be better.

```
public IEnumerable GetDeployHistoryTableDate(int nodeId)
{
        if (nodeId == 0)
        {
             return new List<object>();
        }
        using (var session = sessionFactoryProject.OpenSession())
        {
               using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
               {
                   var items = session.Query<DeployHistory>()
                      .Where(i => i.NodeId == nodeId)
                      .OrderByDescending(i => i.Id)
                      .Select(i => new
                             {
                                 i.EndTime,
                                 i.Result
                             })
                             .First().ToString();

                transaction.Commit();
                return items;
               }
         }
  }
```

Comment: If you didn't call `ToString` on the result, then you'd have an object with your two properties you could use.

Comment: Have a entity to hold the result. public IEnumerable<myresult>  GetDeployHistoryTableDate(int nodeId) and then in the select query .Select(i => new myresult
                             {
                                 i.EndTime,
                                 i.Result
                             })
                             .First(). myresult will have tow properties EndTime and Result.

Comment: You could return the whole row as one object and den later simply access the columns of your row object. Another option would be to return a Tuple<string, string> but then you also could create a new class that can hold your two values. And if your rows represent entities, you could instead of returning the row, return a Object of that entitie type. I would choose such entity if i have to handle the data longer and maybe pass them trough some other functions cause this way it is encapsulated and you can easily add other stuff later on, but it depends what your trying to achieve.

Comment: @CharlesMager If I do not call ToString on the result, the `return items` at the end of the functions reports an incompatibility error.

Comment: @CharlesMager Or...if I manage to return this as an object by changing the function signature to ` public object GetDeployHistoryTableDate(int nodeId)`, how do i obtain the individual members over at the calling function?

Comment: @user1173240 you can't. Create another class to hold your values.

Comment: @CharlesMager On both sides, right, i.e., creating another class, on this function as well as the calling function, because a cast from object to a helpful type at the calling function will probably be invalid...?